# # of random walks in a regular tree

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk, trees

Is there a (easy) way to count the (expected) number of random walks of length $k$, in $d$-regular tree with depth $k$, such that they end in the same starting node?

- $d$-regular: degree of each vertex is $d$.

Note that it's asking for "walk" (not path), meaning that you can visit each node multiple times, otherwise the answer would be 1.

Some thoughts:

If we don't have the condition of ending in the same starting node, it should be easy. Since from each node we can transition to $d$ other nodes, the count is $d^k$. However I think this condition complexity changes the nature of the problem.

Another attempt was to use recursion, but I think it doesn't work, because I didn't find a way to decouple probability functions (the events, to be more accurate).

Comment: Can you describe the setup a bit more?  Where do the walk start?  What are the legal moves?  Is the tree complete?  Why don't you just say, "such that they end in the same node?"  That is, what's conveyed with "starting?"  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Starting point: start at any vertex. Since it is regular, the starting point should not matter. Legal moves: uniformly move to neighboring vertices. Since it is d-regular, transition prob. to each neighbor is 1/d.

Comment: In a  regular graph each node has the same degree. In a finite tree, there is always a node with degree one, so only d=1 seems possible. I assume that you mean something else with the term "d-regular tree with depth k", but at least I (and I guess  Fabio Somenzi as well ) do not understand what it means. Are you maybe talking about an infinite d-regular tree?

Comment: Take a look at this question, which may be what you are looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43693/a-generating-function-for-walks-on-a-rooted-infinite-regular-tree